# Locate text which loads dynamically Python Selenium WebDriver

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My problem is that I am trying to get the text of the element, which fills up with HTML content dynamically. Here is HTML source code. The last div:

```html
<div data-bind="with: dataForRatingPopup"></div>
```

Fills with HTML code when the mouse enters the first div:

```html
<div class="star-rating-wrap" data-bind="event: { mouseenter: mouseEnter, mouseleave: mouseLeave, click: click }, css: { 'has-supplier': emex.context.userIsInOptovikInterface }">
    <div class="star-rating rating-6" data-bind="css: css"></div>
    <div data-bind="with: dataForRatingPopup"></div>
</div>
```

How can I get the text of this element using Selenium WebDriver?

Comment: looks there is no text in html code, are you looking for any attribute?

Comment: XPATH search for DIV with data-bind="with: dataForRatingPopup"

Comment: How did you try? Where is your code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use webdriverwait function for this

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(
            EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@data-bind, "dataForRatingPopup")]'), "txt you want to match")
        )
```

Above code will wait up to 100 seconds to find a div (whose @data-bind attribute contains the value "dataForRatingPopup") which contains the text "txt you want to match"

Useful links :
https://christopher.su/2015/selenium-chromedriver-ubuntu/ (You can skip pyvirtualdisplay usage in that)

http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html#simple-usage

Comment: I don't understand what this answer has to do with this question.

Comment: @JeffC During scraping with requests module you can get only static content(not which is loading via JS like in angular base site), For this purpose, you have to use selenium with any webdriver (Firfox, chrome or phantomJS). Above code snippet is for waiting for an element after page load.

Comment: There is no `A` tag in the provided HTML let alone any tag that contains the text "View all claims"... so I still don't understand what this answer has to do with this question.

Comment: OP is trying to *get* the text from the specified `DIV`... not search for a `DIV` based on contained text. This still doesn't apply

Comment: @JeffC Updated my answer to be more specific to question